# Style default TextBox ContextMenu in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, styles, contextmenu

I've tried to style the `ContextMenu` of a customized `TextBox` in WPF adding `<Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource ProfessionalContextMenu}" />` to avoid this ugly appearance (the `MenuItem` Style is applied globally):

[image]

Using this `ContextMenu` style:

```
<Style x:Key="ProfessionalContextMenu" TargetType="{x:Type ContextMenu}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF494949"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
</Style>
```

But it throws an exception (XamlParseException).

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the XAML. Are you sure it's not happening somewhere else?

Comment: Can you post full exception message, that might some clues to where the problem is?

Answer (score 2):

You trying assign `Style` to `ContextMenu` (`<Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource ProfessionalContextMenu}" />`) and here is the problem probably.

Try using following code:

```
<TextBox>          
    <TextBox.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu Style="{StaticResource ProfessionalContextMenu}">
            <MenuItem Header="MenuItem1" />
            <MenuItem Header="MenuItem2" />
        </ContextMenu>
    </TextBox.ContextMenu>
</TextBox>
```